# Why add indexes to these columns in the Database?

Tags: index, database-theory, rails

I am trying to get my head around this code. It's from the Rails Tutorial Book and is part of the process of making a twitter like application.

```
   class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followed_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :relationships, :follower_id
    add_index :relationships, :followed_id
    add_index :relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

- Since their are only 2 columns (follower_id and followed_id) why would their be a need for an index?
- Does the index sort them is some way? It just seems a bit strange to me to add an index to a table with 2 columns?
- What does the index do to the rows?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you add an index to the back of a book? So you can quickly look up a *word* and see which *page numbers* it's on.

Why is it fast to look up a word in a book index? Because the words in the index are *sorted*.

Similarly, in a database index, you can quickly look up a *value* and get the *rows* it is on.

1. The usage of indexes, and the number of columns, is not particularly related. You can have zero, one, or many indexes on (almost) any column in a table.
2. The index itself is a sorted structure, to allow for fast look-ups, but does not sort the physical rows of its table†.
3. An index doesn't do anything to the rows. It is a separate structure that points to rows. For example, if you're looking for follower_id 3, you could look at the index and it says, follower_id 3 is on rows 4, 9 and 99. This is faster than looking at every row for follower_id 3.

The last index in your example is a unique index, which prevents one from following the same person twice. An exception will be raised if you try to enter {follower_id=1, followed_id=2} and then {follower_id=1, followed_id=2}.

A unique index is similar to a primary key (though a primary key may not contain nulls), and is identical to a unique constraint in many systems††.

A final question to ask is, is it easy to be the guy that maintains the index of a book if the author is making a lot of revisions to the book?

† unless it's a clustered index

†† In Postgres a unique index may use expressions whereas a constraint may not